# changing notification message

Tags: android, notifications, intentservice

I have downloading IntentService, can I put progress about downloading into notification and change it when progress changes?

```
private void sendNotification() {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
           this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
        new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Downloading")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText("Downloaded "+progress+" %"));

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

In method onHandleIntent() I start downloading and I need to change text of the notification on progress change.

Comment: See official doc: [Displaying Progress in a Notification](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html)

Comment: You can update existing notification with new text, call mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build()); with another contents